# hide Cancel and Ok button but keep X button working antd Modal?

Tags: reactjs, antd

im using the antd model to popup a visual. I need to remove the cancel and Ok button but keep the X button working so that i can close the popup using that button.

i removed the Cancel and Ok button using below code **but after that clicking on X is not working and can't close**

```
            <Modal
                title="Lost Assets"
                visible={isModalOpen}
                width="95%"
                style={{ top: "20px" }}
                bodyStyle={{ height: "calc(100vh - 170px)" }}
                footer={null}
```

How can i make the **X button workable** and make it **a little bit large in size?**

[image]

Remove the below two buttons and keep the top X workable.

Comment: can you provide an image of that or a codepen link?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/j8o68z can you please try it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the antd documentation for the Modal they have a prop called `closable` that, if you set to true, it will render the "x" button. To style it you just have to target it's css className or you can use your own "x" component by using the `closeIcon` prop on the Modal as well. For further reading you can go the [original Docs](https://ant.design/components/modal/#API)

Comment: yes i have added `closable={true}` but it gave me a syntax error.

Comment: what is your antd version?

Comment: "antd": "^4.21.6",
  "antd-img-crop": "^4.2.4",

Comment: hmmm weird, because your version contains the closable prop (which by default should be true) so it should render the closable, it could be because onCancel is not set, did you inspect the element to make sure it's not there? could be that the `width: 95%` is hiding it

Comment: yes, you are right !!! we need to set oncancel with footer={null}.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onCancel={handleCancel}` method and set the value `isModalOpen = false` to hide the modal.

example:

`const handleCancel = () => { setIsModalOpen(false) }`

Comment: Thanks for replying. But this one is not working. what i want to do is remove cancel and ok button but keep X button and need to that button workable. question updated with image

Comment: As per the doc, set as footer={null} when you don't need default buttons

Answer (score 0):

you can set footer null like this

```
<Modal footer={null} onCancel={handleCancel}> </Modal>
```

and don't remove **handleCancel** function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).